# Using variables assigned with heredoc content in a Bash script via Sed

Tags: git, bash, sed, ansible, heredoc

I'm trying to replace some configuration data in Ansible files with values that I have assigned with heredoc. The heredoc data contains values that are retrieved from Git.

The end goal is to retrieve Git config and update some Ansible var files with their values.

I don't know how to resolve the error

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 6: unterminated `s' command
```

The Bash script looks like the following

```
update_ansible_config()
{
    # Attempt to get the most relevant git configuration (global, local then repo)
    GIT_USER=$(git config user.name)
    GIT_EMAIL=$(git config user.email)

    if [ -z "${GIT_EMAIL}" ] || [ -z "${GIT_USER}" ]; then
        echo "Please set up your Git credentials (User and Email)"
        exit 1
    fi

    # Update the ansible vars/all.yml with the Git configuration

    # This is the pattern we are looking for
    read -r -d '' SEARCH_CONFIG <<EOF
git:
    install: '1'
    user:
        email:.*
        name:.*
EOF

    # This is the replacement
    read -r -d '' REPLACEMENT_CONFIG <<EOF
git:
    install: '1'
    user:
        email: '${GIT_EMAIL}'
        name:. '${GIT_USER}'
EOF

    CONFIG=test.yml

    # Debugging
    #echo "${SEARCH_CONFIG}"
    #echo "${REPLACEMENT_CONFIG}"
    set -x

    # Do the replacement
    sed -i 's/'"${SEARCH_CONFIG}"'$/'"${REPLACEMENT_CONFIG}"/ "${CONFIG}"
}
```

Perhaps I'm over-complicating the approach and there is a better alternative. I want to ensure that I only update the email and name keys when they exist under the git -> user keys.

Edit -

After looking at the answer from @chridd I am closer.

The Bash output now looks like

```
+ sed -i 's/git:
    install: '\''1'\''
    user:
        email:.*
        name:.*$/git:
    install: \'\''1\'\''
    user:
        email: '\''foo@bar'\''
        name: '\''Foo Bar'\''/' test.yml
sed: -e expression #1, char 6: unterminated `s' command
```

I'm still doing something incorrectly. Also, I didn't need to use the convoluted script to get the Git config (updated)

Comment: Newlines should be replaced with `\n`. Also read [this FAQ](http://sed.sourceforge.net/sedfaq5.html#s5.10). I recommend using Perl instead of sed.

Comment: Thanks @RuslanOsmanov I'll take a look at that.

Comment: while `sed` means `stream` editor, it is really a line editor. Without jumping thru a lot of hoops, it can't match the multiline SEARCH_CONFIG variable you have defined. If you really need/want to use `sed`, then work your way thru this tutorial, and you'll know everything sed can do (and can't): https://grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html . Good luck.

Comment: AND I don't think you need `$(echo "...")`. just `sed -i "s/$SEARCH/$REPL/" file` would be enough, except that you have `\n` chars embedded in `$SEARCH`, and that won't work.

Comment: @shelter - I have started to go through that too. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is where it says `$(echo "${SEARCH_CONFIG}")`.  `echo` outputs a newline after its output, which means that if `$SEARCH_CONFIG` is "foo" and `$REPLACEMENT_CONFIG` is "bar", then the command `sed` is trying to execute looks like

```
s/foo
/bar
/
```

`sed` interprets this as three separate commands since it's three separate lines, and complains since `s/foo` isn't a complete command.  In this case, the `echo` is unnecessary; just use `${SEARCH_CONFIG}` directly without the `echo`:

```
    sed -i 's/'"${SEARCH_CONFIG}"/"${REPLACEMENT_CONFIG}"/ "${CONFIG}"
```

If you specifically care about it being at the end of the line, then add a `$` after the regular expression (make sure to quote it):

```
    sed -i 's/'"${SEARCH_CONFIG}"'$/'"${REPLACEMENT_CONFIG}"/ "${CONFIG}"
```

Comment: Thanks @chridd - That has gotten me closer.

My output now looks like this

    + sed -i 's/git:
    install: '\''1'\''
    user:
        email:.*
        name:.*$/git:
    install: \'\''1\'\''
    user:
        email: '\''foo@bar'\''
        name: '\''Foo Bar'\''/' test.yml
sed: -e expression #1, char 6: unterminated `s' command

Comment: The question has been updated as a result of your answer. Thanks.